# How to sort by frontmatter fields using GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I want to sort my `.md` files based on a `frontmatter`-field, in this case "id", but for some reason I don't know it is not working.

```
allMarkdownRemark(
   sort: {fields: frontmatter___id, order: ASC}
   filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {regex: "/(cars)/.*\\.md$/"}}
  ) {
      edges {
          node {
             frontmatter {
                 id
                 fabrication
                 engine
                 type
              }
         }
     }
}
```

When I run this with the `graphiql`-query tool, it works, but in my application it does not work and I get the error `In field "fields": Expected type "MarkdownRemarkConnectionSortByFieldsEnum", found "frontmatter___id".`

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it myself.

wrapping `[]` around did the trick: so it is:

```
sort: {fields: [frontmatter___id], order: ASC}
```

Comment: Do you know why `___` is used?